# Alamofire-image loading wrong Image inside uicollectionview cell

Tags: swift2, alamofire, alamofireimage

i have been using alamofire-image library to display image from url inside uicollectionview cell.

i have noticed that most of time its displays the right image but sometimes displays wrong image(most of the time previous cell image). 
how to overcome this problem.

```
      func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
        cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

          let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell",forIndexPath: indexPath) as! myCollectionViewCell

          cell.titleLabelCell.text = element[indexPath.row]["title"]
          cell.generLabelCell.text  = element[indexPath.row]["gener"]

          let URL = NSURL(string: "\(element[indexPath.row]["banner_site_url"])" )!

          cell.mImageView.af_setImageWithURL(URL)

          return cell
      }
```

Comment: I believe you're downloading in the background. The issue here is that when the scroll is fast, the cell has already moved to a different section. And when the image returned, it gets assigned to the wrong cell. I have the same issue. I thinking of setting up the request url string as variable so the correct image is assigned.

Answer (score 4):

You have to break the connection with any image download request that may be in progress when you reuse the cell.

You can find a good tutorial written by [Todd Kramer](http://www.tekramer.com/) at:

[Downloading, Caching, & Decoding Images Asynchronously In Swift With Alamofire: Part 1](http://www.tekramer.com/downloading-images-asynchronously-in-swift-with-alamofire/)

Note the implementation of the cell view class *PhotoCollectionViewCell*. It calls the member function *reset*, which cancels any existing request, before launching a request for the current image.

If the images are small and likely to be reused I tend to cancel the cell update rather than the retrieval.

Read the whole thing.

Comment: kind a late,migrated to kingfisher library. still the best answer and will definitely try to implement the above

Comment: I just read this. So this solved my issue by basically creating a shared instance to terminate the background request when new one comes in.

Comment: Sorry I was too late to help you.